# Debugging JAGS and BUGS

Tags: r, bugs, jags

I'm working on a not-too-fancy Bayesian model in R and JAGS.  The goal is to isolate coder errors in a content analysis task.  Code and output are given below.

The larger question is how to go about debugging JAGS. (I assume that the same advice would hold for BUGS as well.) What am I supposed to make of an error like "Invalid initial values" when there are nearly a dozen different initial values?

Here's my R code:

```
library(rjags)
library(R2jags)

#Load the data
toy_data <- read.csv("toy_data.csv")

#Rescale data
rescaled_data <- toy_data[,c(3:(2+K))]
for( k in c(1:K) ){
  col <- rescaled_data[,c(k)]
  rescaled_data[,c(k)] <- (col-min(col))/(max(col)-min(col))
}

codes <- as.matrix(rescaled_data)
doc_ids <- toy_data$docid
coder_ids <- toy_data$coderid

N <- nrow( toy_data ) #Number of document codings
D <- max(toy_data$docid) #Number of documents
I <- max(toy_data$coderid) #Number of coders
K <- dim(toy_data)[2]-2 #Number of attributes

#Package info for jags
jags.data <- list( "doc_ids", "coder_ids", "codes", "N", "D", "I", "K" )
jags.params <- c("z","mu","sigma","sigma_i","sigma_k","mu_dk","alpha_k","beta_k","alpha_i","beta_i")
jags.inits <- list(
  "z" <- matrix(rnorm(N*K),nrow=N,ncol=K),
  "mu" <- runif(1)*10,
  "sigma" <- rgamma(1,10),
  "sigma_i" <- rgamma(I,10),
  "sigma_k" <- rgamma(K,10),
  "mu_dk" <- as.matrix(rnorm(D*K),nrow=D,ncol=K),
  "alpha_k" <- rgamma(1,10),
  "alpha_i" <- rgamma(1,10),
  "alpha_i" <- rgamma(1,10),
  "beta_i" <- rgamma(1,10)
  )

#Fit the model
jagsfit <- jags(
  model.file="coder_model.txt",
  data=jags.data, 
  inits=jags.inits,
  jags.params,
  n.iter=5000,
)
```

Here's the JAGS model:

```
model {
  for( n in 1:N ){   #Loop over codings
    for( k in 1:K ){ #Loop over attributes
      #d <- doc_ids[n]    #Get document index
      #i <- coder_ids[n]  #Get code index
      codes[n,k] ~ dbern(p[n,k])
      logit(p[n,k]) <- z[n,k]
      z[n,k] ~ dnorm( mu_dk[doc_ids[n],k], sigma_k[k]*(1+sigma_i[coder_ids[n]]) )
    }
  }

  for( d in 1:D ){
    for( k in 1:K ){
      mu_dk[d,k] ~ dnorm( mu, sigma )
    }
  }

  for( k in 1:K ){   #Loop over attributes
    sigma_k[k] ~ dgamma( alpha_k, beta_k )
  }
  for( i in 1:I ){   #Loop over coders
    sigma_i[i] ~ dgamma( alpha_i, beta_i )
  }

  #Noninformative priors over alphas and betas
  mu ~ dnorm( 0, 10 )
  sigma ~ dgamma(10,8)
  alpha_k ~ dgamma(10,8)
  beta_k ~ dgamma(10,8)
  alpha_i ~ dgamma(10,8)
  beta_i ~ dgamma(10,8)
}
```

Here's the data:

```
"docid","coderid","Answer.1","Answer.2"
1,1,3,3
1,2,4,1
1,3,7,2
2,1,3,3
2,2,4,4
2,4,3,1
3,1,3,3
3,2,4,3
3,3,3,4
4,4,5,1
4,5,6,2
4,2,4,3
5,2,5,4
5,3,3,1
5,4,7,2
6,1,3,3
6,5,4,1
6,2,5,2
```

And here's the R output:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
   Graph Size: 352

Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = inits, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Invalid initial values
```

Comment: No idea if this is what is causing your problem or just a copy/paste error, but the syntax you are using in the assignment of `jags.inits` is wrong.  It should be `list(foo = bar)`, not `list(foo <- bar)`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran your model with rjags package. I have not provided any initial value since JAGS can produce them for you. You can see the error below

```
> m <- jags.model(file = "model.txt", n.chain = 1)
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(file = "model.txt", n.chain = 1) : RUNTIME ERROR:
Index out of range for node mu_dk
```

You have specified the codes[n, k] variable in the likelihood to have a Bernoulli distribution as

```
codes[n, k] ~ dbern(p[n, k])
```

which should have values of 0 or 1, but in the data you have

```
> codes
      Answer.1  Answer.2
 [1,]     0.00 0.6666667
 [2,]     0.25 0.0000000
 [3,]     1.00 0.3333333
 [4,]     0.00 0.6666667
 [5,]     0.25 1.0000000
 [6,]     0.00 0.0000000
 [7,]     0.00 0.6666667
 [8,]     0.25 0.6666667
 [9,]     0.00 1.0000000
[10,]     0.50 0.0000000
[11,]     0.75 0.3333333
[12,]     0.25 0.6666667
[13,]     0.50 1.0000000
[14,]     0.00 0.0000000
[15,]     1.00 0.3333333
[16,]     0.00 0.6666667
[17,]     0.25 0.0000000
[18,]     0.50 0.3333333
```

How can codes[n, k] have a Bernoulli distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the same model in WinBugs or OpenBugs. They generally give slightly more detailed error messages, so you might get something more useful in this specific case, too.